# BOOT_COMPLETED not triggered on a Gionee device with Lollipop ver

Tags: android, bootcompleted

UPDATE : I am receiving BOOT_COMPLETED on Gionee but only if I follow these steps -
1. Open "Auto start" and then close it
2. Open the app and close it

If I do above steps and then turn off and on the phone, BOOT_COMPLETED gets triggered. Next time if I just turn it off and on, it is not triggered. Am able to simulate this consistently. What might be the reason ?

---

I have this declared in the manifest. It is working on phones like Samsung, Motorola etc but on Gionee I found that the receiver is not getting triggered on phone bootup. The phone has Lollipop ver. Please let me know what might be missing here. Appreciate your help.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my Gionee Phone:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="com.gionee.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this need any additional permission that is Gionee specific ?

Comment: did u add permissions??

Comment: Just this one - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: It is working with this permission on Samsung, Moto, OnePlus etc

Comment: post your receiver too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143830/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-roy).